Why is the FFT output divided by the data length?
I am working with FFT using NumPy in Python, and I noticed that it's common to divide the output of the np.fft.fft function by the length of the data array. Here's a simplified example of my code:
L = 1024  # Length of the data array
x = np.array([3, 1, 0, ..., 2])  # Data array with 1024 elements
output = np.fft.fft(x) / L

I understand that np.fft.fft(x) computes the discrete Fourier Transformation of the array x. But, I don't know why the resulting array output is divided by L (the length of x).
What is the purpose of dividing the FFT output by the array length L?

In short, there needs to be a scaling by $1/N$ in either the forward or backward direction of the Fourier transform (or by $1/\sqrt{N}$ in both directions). Issues of normalization with Fourier transforms are always annoying, because different places have different preferences. For example, mathematically it is almost always easiest to work with unitary transforms, which want symmetrized $1/\sqrt{N}$ transforms. But numerically, introducing square roots is a terrible idea --- and the FFT is particularly useful for numerical computation.
Directly in python, I'll note that dividing by the length is the same as doing a "forward" transform. You can verify directly, for example, via
import numpy as np
x = np.array([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9])

np.fft.fft(x)/len(x)
# [ 3.83333333+0.00000000e+00j,  0.41666667+1.29903811e+00j,
#   -0.91666667+1.01036297e+00j,  0.16666667-7.40148683e-17j,
#   -0.91666667-1.01036297e+00j,  0.41666667-1.29903811e+00j]

np.fft.fft(x, norm="forward")
# [ 3.83333333+0.00000000e+00j,  0.41666667+1.29903811e+00j,
#   -0.91666667+1.01036297e+00j,  0.16666667-7.40148683e-17j,
#   -0.91666667-1.01036297e+00j,  0.41666667-1.29903811e+00j])

In practice, I suspect that what's really going on is that someone who doesn't really understand what direction of transform they're applying is writing code that works. There is a lot of this out there.

I don't think $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ makes any sense mathematically either. DFT is supposed to the discrete version of the Fourier series. The factor $\frac{1}{N}$ naturally arises as the inversion of the function's period (see my answer). I believe this is result of people mistakingly believe that the DFT is idempotent.

FFT is DFT, which is a discrete version of Fourier Series. If take a look at the Fourier series, you would see the term $\dfrac{1}{P}$ appearing in the calculation of coefficients of the Fourier series. It's the inverse of the period $P$ of the function because the integral is calculated by averaging the intergrated expression over the entire cycle. To recover the function via Fourier series, however, only requires adding the terms without any scaling
The formula of DFT assumes that $P = 1$, that's why you don't see the term $\frac{1}{P}$. Which means the number of samples is the number of sample in one unit cycle, which is the sampling frequency, therefore $F_s = N$.
In real situations, however, it's quite often that the sampling frequency is chosen as $1$. In that case, $P = N$ and thus the scaling factor of $\dfrac{1}{N}$
